# Scatter Plot on Projected Map is not in Correct Location

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, cartopy

I have the trajectory of a hurricane[image: Hurrican Florence correct location]. In a "conventional" map CRS, the trajectory of the hurricane is correct

However, when I use a unconventional projection, the location of the hurricane is off. It starts East of North America and then goes West over the land. Why is that?

[image: Hurrican Florence Wrong Location]

Here is how I try it

```
data = {'Lat':{0:12.9,2:12.9,4:13.2,6:13.6,8:13.7,10:13.8,12:14.2,14:14.5,16:14.8,18:16.0,20:17.0,22:17.9,24:18.3,26:18.9,28:19.7,30:20.7,32:22.0,34:23.4,36:24.6,38:25.1,40:25.0,42:24.8,44:24.5,46:24.6,48:24.4,50:24.6,52:25.0,54:25.9,56:26.4,58:27.1,60:28.0,62:28.5,64:29.4,66:30.4,68:31.5,70:32.5,72:33.1,74:33.6,76:33.9,78:34.1,80:34.1,82:34.0,84:33.9,86:33.7,88:33.6,90:33.6,92:33.6,94:33.7,96:34.0,98:35.5,100:38.5,102:39.8,104:42.6},'Long':{0:-18.4,2:-19.4,4:-20.9,6:-21.4,8:-22.7,10:-24.7,12:-25.5,14:-26.7,16:-27.8,18:-30.2,20:-33.2,22:-35.9,24:-38.7,26:-41.0,28:-42.5,30:-43.9,32:-45.7,34:-47.2,36:-48.6,38:-49.8,40:-51.8,42:-53.2,44:-54.3,46:-55.2,48:-56.3,50:-57.7,52:-60.0,54:-62.4,56:-64.6,58:-66.2,60:-67.9,62:-69.5,64:-70.7,66:-71.8,68:-73.2,70:-74.3,72:-75.1,74:-76.0,76:-76.4,78:-77.2,80:-77.9,82:-78.4,84:-78.8,86:-79.3,88:-79.5,90:-79.8,92:-80.1,94:-80.8,96:-81.8,98:-82.1,100:-82.9,102:-80.2,104:-71.9}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# Invert longitude for plotting in western Hemisphere
df['Long'] = df['Long'] * -1

newCrs = ccrs.RotatedPole(pole_latitude=37.5, pole_longitude=177.5)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax = plt.subplot(projection = newCrs)
ax.coastlines(resolution = '110m')
ax.scatter(df['Long'], df['Lat'], color = 'red', transform = newCrs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `transform` keyword in `ax.scatter` should be the DATA CRS. So, assuming that your indata is fine with PlateCarree crs:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Lat=[i for i in data['Lat'].values()], Long=[i for i in data['Long'].values()]))
 
newCrs = ccrs.RotatedPole(pole_latitude=37.5, pole_longitude=177.5)
dataCrs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax = plt.axes(projection = newCrs)
ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines()
ax.scatter(df['Long'], df['Lat'], color = 'red', transform = dataCrs)
```

gives:
[image: plot showing alternative projection with data points correctly projected]

Please read [this page explaining transforms](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/tutorials/understanding_transform.html) for details and a tutorial.

### Alternative solution (recommending GeoPandas)

Perhaps not a direct answer to your question, but if I do it through GeoPandas (highly recommended), I don't seem to get any problems:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

data = {'Lat':{0:12.9,2:12.9,4:13.2,6:13.6,8:13.7,10:13.8,12:14.2,14:14.5,16:14.8,18:16.0,20:17.0,22:17.9,24:18.3,26:18.9,28:19.7,30:20.7,32:22.0,34:23.4,36:24.6,38:25.1,40:25.0,42:24.8,44:24.5,46:24.6,48:24.4,50:24.6,52:25.0,54:25.9,56:26.4,58:27.1,60:28.0,62:28.5,64:29.4,66:30.4,68:31.5,70:32.5,72:33.1,74:33.6,76:33.9,78:34.1,80:34.1,82:34.0,84:33.9,86:33.7,88:33.6,90:33.6,92:33.6,94:33.7,96:34.0,98:35.5,100:38.5,102:39.8,104:42.6},'Long':{0:-18.4,2:-19.4,4:-20.9,6:-21.4,8:-22.7,10:-24.7,12:-25.5,14:-26.7,16:-27.8,18:-30.2,20:-33.2,22:-35.9,24:-38.7,26:-41.0,28:-42.5,30:-43.9,32:-45.7,34:-47.2,36:-48.6,38:-49.8,40:-51.8,42:-53.2,44:-54.3,46:-55.2,48:-56.3,50:-57.7,52:-60.0,54:-62.4,56:-64.6,58:-66.2,60:-67.9,62:-69.5,64:-70.7,66:-71.8,68:-73.2,70:-74.3,72:-75.1,74:-76.0,76:-76.4,78:-77.2,80:-77.9,82:-78.4,84:-78.8,86:-79.3,88:-79.5,90:-79.8,92:-80.1,94:-80.8,96:-81.8,98:-82.1,100:-82.9,102:-80.2,104:-71.9}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=df.Long,y=df.Lat), crs='wgs84')

newCrs = ccrs.RotatedPole(pole_latitude=37.5, pole_longitude=177.5)
gdf_proj = gdf.to_crs(newCrs)

ax = gdf_proj.plot(figsize=(20,8))
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = gdf_proj.total_bounds
ax.set_xlim(minx-50, maxx+75)
ax.set_ylim(miny-50, maxy+75)
ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs=gdf_proj.crs.to_string(), source=ctx.providers.Stamen.TonerLite)
```

[image: plot showing the correct points on the map using the alternative solution]

### General tips/comments

- You should not need to flip the Longitude coordinates at all.
- Did you check if there are any issues with Matplotlib/Cartopy?
- If you have the Proj4 definition string you do not even need cartopy if using GeoPandas. In this case the `newCrs` variable would become `newCrs = '+ellps=WGS84 +a=6378137.0 +proj=ob_tran +o_proj=latlon +o_lon_p=0.0 +o_lat_p=37.5 +lon_0=357.5 +to_meter=111319.4907932736 +no_defs'`.
- You should probably clean up the use of Pandas DataFrame, storing a dictionary in a column of a dataframe is not really recommended, and probably makes your life more difficult.

Comment: You are writing: "If you have the Proj4 definition string you do not even need cartopy if using GeoPandas.". How would I set the projection of the plot without `cartopy`, but with the `proj4` string?

Comment: @Stophface great question (had to check that it works :])! Basically, in the GeoPandas example I put in you would replace the definition of `newCrs` with the proj4 string (and remove import and reference to cartopy). In this case the proj4 string would make the variable `newCrs = '+ellps=WGS84 +a=6378137.0 +proj=ob_tran +o_proj=latlon +o_lon_p=0.0 +o_lat_p=37.5 +lon_0=357.5 +to_meter=111319.4907932736 +no_defs'`